# Is there a Django's context processor like in Grails?

Tags: grails

I want to output a value which is global in all the templates or even layout in Grails, like Django's context processor where you could render the context and use it as global variable in the templates.

Is there a concept like this in Grails? And, how can I use that in the layout?

Comment: I would also like to know this. What in Grails is closest to Django's context processors?

Comment: This would be an incredibly useful feature if it exists.  I don't know of anything that is universally injected into the GSPs to even compare against.

Comment: Or maybe this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728021/adding-a-variable-to-all-views-in-grails?rq=1

Answer (score -3):

I am not familiar with Django at all.  Looked up Django's context processor in google, I think I get it.  Basically it configures reusable data that gets injected into every template?  Anyway, as far as I know nothing like that exists in Grails.  You can try the following as a workaround.

**Use ApplicationContext**

Every view has access to the applicationContext.  So make a service that holds all the data you need, let's say it is called fooService, and the data item you want is a field in the service called bar (could be a method too of course).  Then in your view do ${applicationContext.fooService.bar}.  Resource for accessing applicationContext in view: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/11/grails-goodness-get-grailsapplication.html.

**Use your layout**

I am not sure about this one, so use at your own risk.  The top one is of course extremely verbose.  It would be annoying to call that over and over again in different views.  So instead, call it once and make it a variable in your layout with g:set.  I think the variable will be available in every view that uses that layout.... but not sure.  Here are the docs for g:set -> http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/set.html.

If I didn't get what context processors do in python I am happy to try again...

Comment: Or you could use controller interceptors: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Controllers/afterInterceptor.html.  Just have every controller extend a base one that adds all necessary variables.